# Why is the file not found?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
#A game about a glue stick that is trying to glue the world back together
import pygame
import sys
import os
import movement

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#STAGNANT VARS
VEL = 10

#Load all image assets here
char = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('../img/player.png')), (100, 200))

pygame.display.set_caption('The Adventures of Glue Boy')

WINDOW_SIZE = (1920, 1080)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE,0,32)


while True: #Game loop (main)

    screen.fill((225,225,225))
    screen.blit(char, (500, 500))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    movement.__init__(char, screen)
    movement.control(keys_pressed, VEL)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

That is my code and for some reason I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\snowb\Desktop\Glue Game\src\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    char = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('../img/player.png')), (100, 200))
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

Can somebody please help me?? I have been staring at this for hours. It might be something that is obvious but I cannot figure it out, I have tried everything in my book that I can think of.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  One thing is there's little point in doing a ```os.path.join()``` on ```../img/player.png```.   Secondly, are you sure that the relative paths as executed by your script is going to the right directory?   It would probably be easier if you used the full path until you are sure where each file is with relation to where and how the script is run.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to your _current working directory_. This is usually the directory you started your python interpreter in. See what you get when you `print(os.getcwd())`. Does the `../img/player.png` file exist relative to this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sufficient to put the files in a sub directory. You also need to set the working directory.
The resource (image, font, sound, etc.) file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python script. You have to make sure that the working directory is set correctly.
The name and path of the python file can be retrieved with [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes) and the current working directory can be changed with [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).
Put the following at the beginning of your code to set the working directory to the same as the script's directory:

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```